# spark-submit with specific python librairies

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-submit

I have a pyspark code depending on third party librairies. I want to execute this code on my cluster which run under mesos.

I do have a zipped version of my python environment that is on a http server reachable by my cluster.

I have some trouble to specify to my spark-submit query to use this environment.
I use both `--archives` to load the zip file and `--conf 'spark.pyspark.driver.python=path/to/my/env/bin/python'` plus  `--conf 'spark.pyspark.python=path/to/my/env/bin/python'` to specify the thing.

This does not seem to work... Do I do something wrong? Do you have any idea on how to do that?

Cheers,
ALex

Answer (score 1):

To submit you zip folder to python spark, you need to send the files using :

```
spark-submit --py-files your_zip your_code.py
```

While using it inside your code, you will have to use below statement:

```
sc.addPyFile("your_zip")
import your_zip
```

Hope this will help!!

Comment: After doing "import your_zip" it says your_zip doesn't exist. Does this work for zipped environments?

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful to some people, if you have dependencies.

I found a solution on how to properly load a virtual environment to the master and all the slave workers:

```
virtualenv venv --relocatable
cd venv 
zip -qr ../venv.zip *

PYSPARK_PYTHON=./SP/bin/python spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./SP/bin/python --driver-memory 4G --archives venv.zip#SP filename.py
```